# Can we use java/kotlin code in flutter with dart code?

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to use java/kotlin in flutter with dart programming language. Java/kotlin has many functionalities which dart is lacking. But flutter is good in UI UX. So I want to use flutter with dart, but java/kotlin also for back-end programming. How can I do that?

Comment: By "back-end programming" do you mean server, or that you want to mix Kotlin and Flutter in an app? If the latter, the short answer is you can, but you shouldn't. Either adopt Compose KMP, or figure out what you need in Dart. Mixing KMP and Flutter is *possible*, but it'll be more work than it's worth.

Comment: Not just server, I mean everything including writing logic and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from the flutter code to the native code and vice versa.

Please check this reference - https://tanya-anand.medium.com/data-pass-between-flutter-and-android-using-the-method-channel-f0e8f7655fe

But this process is used when we want to use some features that are not provided by Flutter but we can fulfill it using native code. for eg - https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget

however, it might not be so efficient to follow this in the complete app and keep the data logic in Java/swift and UI in Flutter using the above-mentioned way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help:

Develop the frontend UI and logic using Flutter and Dart.
Build a backend server using Java or Kotlin.
Establish communication between the Flutter frontend and the backend server using APIs.